# Builtin Variable to access % gain/loss (Pinescript.V5)

Tags: pine-script

What is the Builtin Variable to access % gain/loss represented in the ticker data for an individual bar in  [Pinescript.v5](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can try out this equation here for any percent calcs in Pine or otherwise:

```
(end price - start price) / start price * 100
```

In pine, we could do this for bar to bar change like so:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

perc = (close - close[1]) / close[1] * 100

plot(perc)
```

Cheers, and best of luck with your trading and coding